# Unexpected token 'a', "array(7) {"... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy validando un formulario con javascript para posteriormente enviarlo a un archivo PHP y de hay a la base de datos, lo estoy haciendo con fetch, me recibe los datos pero me dice Unexpected token 'a', "array(7) {"... is not valid JSON y no lo envía al archivo PHP.

Código PHP:

```
include("../data/conexion.php");

$arr = ($_POST);

var_dump($arr);

$ci             = json_encode($arr["ci"]);
$name           = json_encode($arr["name"]);
$tVehiculo      = json_encode($arr["tVehiculo"]);
$tPuesto        = json_encode($arr["tPuesto"]);
$nPuesto        = json_encode($arr["nPuesto"]);
$email_modal    = json_encode($arr["email_modal"]);
$pass_modal     = json_encode($arr["pass_modal"]);
$btn_enviar     = json_encode($arr["enviar_reg"]);

if (isset($btn_enviar)) {
    echo "enviado";
}
```

Código Javascript:

```
submit_form_create?.addEventListener("click", e => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const form_create = document.getElementById("form_create");

  const data        = new FormData(form_create);
  const url         = "./data/data.php";
  
  fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  dataType: 'text'
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(dataForm => {
    console.log(dataForm);
  });
}
```

Yo estoy haciendo una validación de datos el cual no lo coloque por que es mucho código

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega el código necesario, en tu caso JavaScript y PHP para poder identificar el error (Intenta agregar las partes solo necesarias de código, no necesariamente todo el que tienes). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tu tienes un PHP que devuelve un `string` que **NO** es un JSON

```
if (isset($btn_enviar)) {
    echo "enviado"; //<-- un STRING
}
```

Luego en tu `fetch` convertes la respuesta a JSON

```
  .then(res => res.json()) //<-- AQUÍ EL PROBLEMA
  .then(dataForm => {
    console.log(dataForm);
  });
```

Cuando lo que deberías es convertirlo a texto

```
.then(res => res.text()) //Cambiar por .text()
.then(dataForm => {
   console.log(dataForm);
  });
```

Además tienes un `dataType` que no es una opción valida

```
 fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  dataType: 'text' //Esto no existe
})
```

Si lo tienes no dará error, pero no está de sobra aclararlo. Me recuerda a una opción de `jQuery`, no se si por ahí viene la confusión. Acá la [lista de opciones para fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#options)

Comment: realice el cambio que me comentaste, me quito el problema pero ahora lo envía vacío.

Comment: ya encontré el porque lo enviaba vacío, cambie el addEventListener de click a submit y listo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta fue de ayuda, considera marcarla como aceptada y si crees que necesita más contexto dilo, para que a futuro le ayude a alguien más...